# how can I bypass chrome web bluetooth select device prompt

Tags: bluetooth, chromium

Should I build chrome from source to jump over the select device prompt?

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/

```
  try {
    log('Requesting Bluetooth Device...');
    log('with ' + JSON.stringify(options));
    const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(options);

    log('> Name:             ' + device.name);
    log('> Id:               ' + device.id);
    log('> Connected:        ' + device.gatt.connected);
  } catch(error)  {
    log('Argh! ' + error);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's current implementation of Web Bluetooth does not have a way for websites to get a list of permitted devices. With the **upcoming** `Bluetooth.getDevices()` method, a list of BluetoothDevice objects that the current origin has been granted permission to use by the user will be returned. See https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/get-devices.html for an example.

```js
  log('Getting existing permitted Bluetooth devices...');
  navigator.bluetooth.getDevices()
  .then(devices => {
    console.log('> Got ' + devices.length + ' Bluetooth devices.');
    for (const device of devices) {
      console.log('  > ' + device.name + ' (' + device.id + ')');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Argh! ' + error);
  });
```